# Assign a value of two dimensional array to inner html in Java script

Tags: javascript, html, django

```
 var data = JSON.parse("{{ data|escapejs }}");
    for(var x in data){

      // console.log(data[x])
      console.log(data[x][0])
      console.log(data[x][1])
      var x = document.getElementById("dynamic")
      var string = data[x][1];
      document.getElementById("dynamictitle").innerHTML = data[x][0];
      document.getElementById("dynamicimg").src = data[x][1];
    }
```

**here i am taking value for data from views , trying to pass img source and image title....data[x][0] has some text and data[x][1] has image url....can anyone tell why the values are not passing...if i give direct url like .src = 'https:///imageurl' it is working and same for innerhtml
**

Comment: `{{ data|escapejs }}` this is not valid JSON.

Comment: but in console it is printing the data

Comment: It should be throwing an error, like: `JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`. Is this JS inside a django file? Is `{{ data|escapejs }}` being replaced by an actual JSON string?